# Getting only integer from user

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am watching CS50's python lecture. David J Malan writes a program to take a positive integer from the user. Here he uses a function called get_int() written in CS50 python library.
I am trying to emulate him.

```
def main():
    num = get_int("Enter an integer")
    print(num)


def get_int(prompt):
    i =(input(prompt))
    try:
        i = int(i)
        if type(i) == int:                      
            return i
    except ValueError:
        return "not an integer"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have to use the value returned in the program get_positive_int

```
 from get_int import get_int   

 def main():
     i = get_positive_int("Positive integer please")
     print(i)

 def get_positive_int(prompt):
     while True:
         n = get_int(prompt)
         if(n>=1):      # problem here if user enters anything else than int
             break
      return n


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Hence how do I write a better get_int() so that I don't get the error :

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Instead of returning the string "not an integer", it is better practice to return None (or not return anything which implies returning None) to denote failure of some code

Comment: People downvoting my answer please state the reason so that I learn from my mistake. I am new to python programming

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I wanted the solution in this particular scenario where I want to use the get_int() method in the get_positive_int program, I added try block to get_positive_int.python. 
Also in get_int() I added none instead of returning "not an integer"

#### get_int.python

```
def get_int(prompt):
    i =(input(prompt))
    try:
        i = int(i)
        if type(i) == int:                       
            return i
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

#### get_positive_int.python

```
def get_positive_int(prompt):
    while True:
        n = get_int(prompt)
        try:
            if(n>=1):
                break
        except:
            print("not an integer")

   return n
```

Comment: There are a few issues with that `get_int` (starting from the file name, `.python`?). There's no need to check `i`'s type after using `int(i)` - it *will* be an `int`, or it will raise an exception. There's no way that `if` will fail (and what if it did, what would you return?)

Comment: Also, in Python, we rarely ever need to check types. And in the few occasions we do (not here), it's not using `type`, it's better to use `isinstance(obj, type)`, as in `if isinstance(i, int)` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You can greatly simplify that code. Also, `None` is usually used to denote a missing / failed value so you should return that instead of the string "not an integer". Here is an example of one way of approaching it:

```
def get_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None       # Can also just use pass to signify an empty block

i = get_int(s)
if i is not None:
    print('Successful')
```

Comment: If you had `return None` instead of `pass`, you wouldn't need the explanatory comment.

Comment: I agree but it just feels better with pass instead of needlessly specifying return None as the last line in a method. Although that's just me being too picky. Either way should work

Comment: using pass to implicitly return None, rather than actually using `return None` is pretty horrible. I'd even argue that letting the ValueError propagate out of the function is better.

Comment: I don't think the scope of this discussion is even remotely significant to warrant anything being "pretty horrible" but if people have such strong opinions about it, I'll just update the answer

Comment: I agree with @TomDalton: checking for return values is sooo C-ish. Either something _works_, and you have your value returned, or something else happened, and an exception was raised. Either you _deal_ with the exception (for example, re-prompting the question), or you let it bubble up. But **dont** hide an exception and replace it with an invalid return value. Function values should **not**  be statues or error conditions!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Python's version of the CS50 library, but at least the C version of `get_int()` did **not** work as the answers so far: in case of invalid input, `get_int()` ***re-asked user for another input***, looping over and over until a valid input was given.

So, to truly emulate that behavior:

```py
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

There's no need to assign `int(input())` to `i` or to anything. If it didn't raise an exception, then the value **is** a valid integer, and it can be returned right away. No need for `i` to exist, no need for a test for `None` or any condition at all in `while`.

All we need to do is to see it if raised an exception of the `ValueError` type, and that type *only*, letting other exceptions bubble up to the caller.

And if we catch that exception? Just `pass` and the loop will start over and ask for input again.